# Understanding an Implementation of normal conjugate in R

Tags: r, bayesian, normal-distribution, conjugate-prior

I am reading a code for a Bayesian clustering method. Both prior and the likelihood are normally distributed. If I understood correctly, such cases are called "conjugate priors"

My question is about calculating the posterior mean and variance. So it is implemented in the code as following

```
d = nrow (data.i)##number of attributes
n = ncol (data.i)##number of replication for each attribute
Smatrix = matrix (1, nrow=d, ncol=d)##correlation of attributes
Imatrix = Smatrix - 1
diag (Imatrix) = 1

prior.precision = solve (sdWICluster^2 * Smatrix + sdTSampling^2 * Imatrix) #inverting the prior correlation matrix (prior.precision)
prior.mean = cluster.mean # mean of each clusters

sample.precision = sdResidual^(-2) * Imatrix
sample.mean = apply (data.i, 1, mean)#mean for each cluster

post.cov = solve (as.matrix(prior.precision + n*sample.precision)) # posterior covariance matrix
post.mean = as.vector (post.cov %*% (prior.precision %*% prior.mean + n*sample.precision %*% sample.mean)) # posterior of the mean
```

it seems the code has take the following formula,

$\mu_{po} = C_{po}\times((\mu_{pr} \times \tau_{pr})+(n\times\tau_{li}\times\mu_{li}))$

$C_{po} = \tau_{pr} + n\times\tau_{li}$

As I said, this is the case of conjugates of normal distributions with unknown mean but variance known; however, it does not fit to the formula I have from [here](http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~plam/teaching/methods/conjugacy/conjugacy_print.pdf). (or may be it does by my eye is not able to catch). I appreciate if someone make some comments about the code and the formula

Comment: You said:  "*Both prior and the likelihood are normally distributed. If I understood correctly, such cases are called "conjugate priors"*" -- in this case, yes, though more generally conjugacy is understood as the posterior and the prior having the same form, which may or may not require the likelihood to be of the same form (in the parameter(s), naturally, not the random variable for the data), depending on the situation. It's often the case that the likelihood is in the same form as well, however.

Comment: I liked your comment ! 1) so regarding the likelihood, the distribution is not important but the parameters ?! 2) where the sampling takes place? we sample from the likelihood to estimate the posterior distributions ?

Comment: (1) The likelihood is seen a function of the parameters conditional on the (fixed) data. Your prior and posterior are distributions over the parameters. In some cases of conjugacy, the likelihood can be seen as a distribution over the parameters of the same form. (2) I am not sure what you mean here. What sampling are you referring to?

Comment: I am getting enlightened ! so, if the case is not a conjugate prior to estimate the posterior sampling methods are applicable, such as MCMC or gibbs sampling. So, I assume, they sample from the prior.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're getting at there, perhaps you can clarify. You can use MCMC (Gibbs sampling is a special case of MCMC) with conjugate priors or non-conjugate priors (though Gibbs sampling is easier with conjugate priors). You can do Bayesian calculations that don't use MCMC with either conjugate or non-conjugate priors. None of them sample the prior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same formula, just with slightly different notation.  Notice that in the link, $\tau_0^2$ is the prior variance, not the prior precision.  In the link's notation, the prior precision is $1/\tau_0^2$.  So, in your notation, $\tau_{pr} = 1/\tau_0^2$ and $\tau_{li} = 1/\sigma^2$.

The formula in the code is correct.  But you made a slight mistake in writing out the formula from the code.  Solve takes the inverse, so

$C_{p0} = ( \tau_{pr} + n*\tau_{li})^{-1}$

Comment: Oh, I see, weird. I could make the variant but for the mean, I can only make the numerator not the "denominator". So if I replace $\rho_{pr}$ and $\rho_{li}$ in the code, equation, it will end up as $\frac{\mu_{pr}}{\tau_{pr}^2} + n \frac{\mu_{li}}{\sigma^2}$, but in the link, there is a $\frac{1}{\tau^2}+\frac{n}{\sigma^2}$ as a denominator.

Comment: @user4581  Oh, notice that post.cov = solve(). Will edit my answer accordingly.